# Error: Could not find or load main class simon.Game

Tags: java, eclipse, class, program-entry-point

I've searched in previous posts but cant seem to find the solution, my code worked perfectly until i did something wrong , and now i get "Error: Could not find or load main class gaming.Game"
I think i might have deleted something in the eclipse configurations, How can i solve this?

Comment: Please can you post your class which contains the main?

Answer (score 1):

Your title's error does not match the one you wrote in your question.

The "simon.Game" says that the Game class is in a package called simon. The other error you posted says that it's inside gaming package. This is important.

You can go into eclipse's run configuration and point to the correct class that has the main method.

Answer (score 0):

With eclipse, it is sometimes necessary to remove a project and re-import it in order to solve problems like this. When removing the project, be sure not to leave "delete project contents on disk" checked.

Comment: After deleting every thing and re-importing it, it got back to working mode! thank you